# Want org data totals by date for multiple dates in a single results table from a query on a transactions table

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations

The problem, near as I can explain it, is I can't figure out how to feed dates into another query one by one to produce results in a single table. I'm trying to treat a query that creates totals like a function that I feed dates into. One date, one result row, next date, next result row. I looked at loops, which most people seem to disparage. I've looked at somehow combining two CTEs, one that builds my dates table and the other that runs the totals. For someone still new to sql, this is beyond me right now.

Background:

In my system is a "transactions" table that adds a row every time a change is made to certain organizational parameters like org type, org subtype and org status in other tables. Each new row records the status for all variables for that org at that moment. The rows are unique based on org id and update dttm.

| Org ID | Org Status | Org type | Update DTTM | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55323 | 3 | 10 | 8/15/2002 12:00:00 AM | ... |
| 14942 | 4 | 11 | 5/1/2008 10:39:44 AM | ... |
| 14942 | 4 | 10 | 9/19/2008 12:00:30 AM | ... |
| 19002 | 4 | 10 | 3/27/2023 9:00:14 AM | ... |

On any given day, a few dozen orgs are updated resulting in a few dozen new rows. Some orgs are updated every couple weeks and have a lot of rows in the table. Others don't get updated very often, and the latest row might have been written months or years in the past, but nevertheless that row would represent the current system status for that org since there have been no changes recorded since.

I can effectively produce a system snapshot by sorting by org_id then update_dttm descending, then taking the first row per org after applying a where clause update_dttm < whatever snapshot date. Going further, I can also use a count or sum function to calculate the total number of orgs in each status state at on a given date. What I can't do is produce a query that would show me the totals for a series of dates in a single results table.

This is as close as I've come:

```
DECLARE @Start date
DECLARE @End date 
DECLARE @counter date
set @Start = '2020-01-01'  --could be any start date from this century
set @End = getdate()
set @counter = @Start
while @counter <= @End
begin
    with Moment as
        (
        select ORG_ID, ORG_NAME, ORG_NUM_NAME, ORG_TYPE, ORG_SUBTYPE, STATUS, UPDATE_DTTM, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ORG_ID  
            ORDER BY ORG_ID, UPDATE_DTTM desc 
                ) AS [ROW NUMBER]
        from TRANSACTIONS_TABLE

        where UPDATE_DTTM < @counter
        )
    select count(case STATUS when '4' then 1 else null end) as Active, 
    count(case STATUS when '6' then 1 else null end) as Closed, 
    count(case STATUS when '5' then 1 else null end) as Dormant,
    @counter as SystemDate
    from Moment
    where [ROW NUMBER] = 1
    set @counter = (Select Dateadd(Month, 1, @counter))  --next result from next month
end
```

It gives me the totals for each system date queried, but each row in the result is its own table.

[results tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S90sS.png)

I'm looking for a single table of results. Ultimately, I'd like to take this to Power Query and bring it into Power BI to make a simple visual showing changes over time. If I use that code as it is, Power Query only recognizes the first result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the query inside a `WHILE` loop, you get a result per iteration. A quick fix is to use a temp table and insert the result into the temp table and and the end of the while loop, you select from the temp table.

A better solution is not to use then none performant while loop at all. Do it in a single query. (the inner query in cross apply are basically your original with slight modification)

```
with 
-- recrusive CTE to generate the list of dates
dates as
(
    select [Date] = @Start
    union all
    select [Date] = dateadd(month, 1, [Date])
    from   dates
    where  [Date] < @End
)
-- and then use the dates to calcualte the Active,Closed,Dormant etc.
select t.Active, t.Closed, t.Dormant, d.Date as SystemDate
from   dates d
       cross apply
       (
         select count(case STATUS when '4' then 1 else null end) as Active, 
                count(case STATUS when '6' then 1 else null end) as Closed, 
                count(case STATUS when '5' then 1 else null end) as Dormant
         from  
         (
           select ORG_ID, STATUS, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORG_ID  
                                         ORDER BY ORG_ID, UPDATE_DTTM desc 
                                    ) AS [RN]
           from  TRANSACTIONS_TABLE
           where UPDATE_DTTM < d.Date  
         ) t
         where RN = 1
       ) t
```

Comment: Outstanding. I knew this had to be possible, and I was even looking at brand-new-topic-to-me cross apply yesterday before I threw up my hands.